# Possible to process same packet in two system in Apache storm?

Tags: apache-storm, azure-iot-hub

It is possible to read same packet in local system as well as deployment using Apache storm because in storm application once packet processes means it will not come again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With azure-iot-hub you can consume the stream of device events using consumer groups (go to the iot hub you have configured and look under Messaging, near the bottom of the blade).  Each consumer group is an independent view of the device event streams.  Consumer groups for Iot Hub work very similar to event-hub consumer groups, so consider information on consumer groups under event-hubs as relevant.

So for your question, one consumer group for local processing and another consumer group for Apache storm; each working thru the stream independently.

Comment: I have added eventhubspout.consumer.group.name in my properties file but i am using EventHubSpoutConfig for reading from iot hub . how to set consumer group to the EventHubSpoutConfig ?

Comment: EventHubSpoutConfig spoutConfig = new EventHubSpoutConfig(username, password,
      namespaceName, entityPath, partitionCount, zkEndpointAddress,
      checkpointIntervalInSeconds, receiverCredits, maxPendingMsgsPerPartition, enqueueTimeFilter);

Comment: I have created the consumer group in the iot hub but how to set consumer group to the eventhubspoutconfig for reading?

Comment: I got the solution we need to set like this :  spoutConfig.setConsumerGroupName("dev"); Thnks Greg

Comment: Make my question up